# execSQL only displayng last line of XML

Tags: java, android, sql

I have seen a lot of similar problems here, but none solved my problem.
Im making an app that put the contents of a XML in a database. Everything is working fine but when I open the app for a second time more and more values are added. I was trying to drop table, drop database, and even deleting the file and none of these worked.
Now I added this code and the app is only parsing the LAST line of the xml to the database, and I really dont know why this happens.

```
myDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );
```

Full code:

XMLHelper:

```
package com.example.partedoxml;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLHelper extends DefaultHandler {
    private String URL_MAIN = "http://he4dless.webege.com/packages.xml";
    String TAG = "XMLHelper";

    Boolean currTag = false;
    String currTagVal = "";
    public PostValue menes = null;
    public ArrayList<PostValue> he4dless = new ArrayList<PostValue>();

    public void get() {
        try{
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader();
            mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
            InputStream mInputStream = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();
            mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream)); 



        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exeption:"+e.getMessage());


        }




    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if(currTag){
            currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
            currTag = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        currTag = false;

        //if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
        //packages.setId(currTagVal);

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
        menes.setName(currTagVal);

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
        menes.setLink(currTagVal);

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("menes"))
            he4dless.add(menes);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Log.i(TAG, "TAG:"+localName);

        currTag = true;
        currTagVal = "";

        if(localName.equals("menes"))
            menes = new PostValue();

    }



}
```

SQLHelper:

```
package com.example.partedoxml;

import java.io.File;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "he4dless";

    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "menes";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    public static final String TAG_1 = "tag1";
    public static final String TAG_2 = "tag2";
    public static final String TAG_3 = "tag3";

    private DbHelper myHelper;
    private Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;



    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                //TAG_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                //TAG_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                //TAG_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );  
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }





}
    public SQLHelper(Context c){
        myContext = c;
    }
    public SQLHelper open(){
        myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
        myDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        myDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );







        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        myHelper.close();
    }
    public long create(String name, String link) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_LINK, link);

        return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.partedoxml;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        new PostAsync().execute();
    }

    class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ProgressDialog pd;
        XMLHelper helper;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Esta porra esta carregando", "Baixando o XML", true, false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            helper = new XMLHelper();
            helper.get();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(PostValue post : helper.he4dless){
                //builder.append("\nId: "+ post.getId());

                builder.append("\nName: "+ post.getName());

                builder.append("\nSection: "+ post.getLink());
                builder.append("\n");


                String name = post.getName();
                String link = post.getLink();

                SQLHelper entry = new SQLHelper(MainActivity.this);

                entry.open();

                entry.create(name, link);
                entry.close();


            }
            tv.setText(builder.toString());
            pd.dismiss();
        }



    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I will be very glad if someone solves this problem

Answer (score 1):

Your `open()` drops and recreates the table, and you reopen the database in each for loop iteration.

Leave schema setup to the helper callbacks such as `onCreate()`. Also, you don't need to reopen the database inside the loop.

Comment: but when I remove open() in MainActivity my app crash

Comment: Open it once before the loop.

Comment: Yeahhhh,thanks, that was the problem, and I didnt realize. It was inside the loop and it was like deleting,adding,deleting,adding,deleting and adding (that the last one)
that was so a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the method open() in SQLHelper performs the following:

```
    //You are calling here an instance of your helper. Good.
    myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
    //This step will get you a database. See my explanatino below to understand what happens here
    myDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //THIS LINES SHOULD BE REMOVED
    //In this step you will delete the database (actually only the table) and ALL data
    myDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    //You create the same database again.
    myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );
```

You are actually doing some work twice. When you try to get the writable database you are already calling the method onCreate if the database does not exists. So that you create the database, you delete it, and you create back again empty.

Your code should be the following in open() method and everything should work:

```
 public SQLHelper open(){
      myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
      myDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Finally, I would like also to highlight a potential problem. On the method OnUpgrade you are setting up that your database is also deleted and created back again when you change the version of the database. That means that everytime you modify the value of DATABASE_VERSION the complete data will dissapear.

If you are interested in modifying a value already in the database, you can update it, for example, for the item with KEY_NAME name you can update the value of KEY_LINK adding link2:

```
 public int create(String name, String link2) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(KEY_LINK, link2);

    return myDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null );

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem, but I really want to delete the database and make again, and then add the values.

Comment: So how I can reset my database every time new contents are parsed from the XML?

Comment: I added an example of how to use the method update change the values of the XML. You can easily extend to other items